# CCButton callback sender different in 64 bit devices

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uitouch, arm64

I have a game in cocos2D v3.00. Everything was ok until I add the arm64 architecture. Now, on 64 devices, each time I have a CCButton callback method the sender is a UITouch and not a CCButton like in 32 bit.

[EDIT]

My code :

```
-(void)addButton
{
    CCButton *myButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"[ Pause ]" fontName:@"Jet Set.ttf" fontSize:18.0f];
    myButton.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    myButton.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.95f);
    myButton.name = @"testbutton";
    [myButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(myButtonPressed:)];
    [self addChild:myButton];
}
-(void)myButtonPressed:(CCButton*)sender
{

        NSLog(@"%s = %@", "sender", sender);
}

  // 32Bits => sender = <CCButton = 0x17e0c180 | Name = button_1>
  // 64Bits => sender = <UITouch: 0x1743841d0>
```

Is there a way to solve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try updating to the latest v3.3, this might be a bug. Also be sure to enable arm64 not just in your app's target but also in any target linked to it. If cocos2d happens to be a separate static library target you will have to change its architecture settings to match those of the app target. Though typically not doing so would result in linker errors.

Comment: It might help if you posted the CCButton creation code, including assignment of the selector.

Comment: I edited my question with the creation code.
For the architechture, all my targets have now the arm64 (the app and ObjectiveChipmunk).

Comment: Looks correct. So maybe do try with a newer cocos2d version.

Comment: Ok, I gone upgrade, even if upgrading cocos2D in an existing project without SpriteBuilder doesn't look so easy. By the way if you know a place where the upgrading process is exaclty describe, I will be very please (sorry as it's not related to my first question). Thnak you.

Comment: I updated to v3.3 and the cast is now ok. Thank you.